# CSV read breaking when last line is \n for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm working on a project with some supplied CSV files that I need to parse and do some manipulation on. One is throwing this error when I try to load it into a file using `CSV.read('path/file.csv')`

```
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 7911).
```

Now when looking at the file, the last line is just blank. It's a `\n` character. I feel like this should not break the CSV read but it is. Now, I could just check the end of the CSV documents and strip any access return carriages/new lines since that seems like it'll work but it doesn't seem like the correct way. Anybody have some advice?

Edit: Using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.5

Comment: try this: http://www.arthurneil.com/ruby-on-rails/csv-parsing-issues-malformedcsverror-unquoted-fields-r-n

Comment: @UriAgassi I saw that on google and tried it. Exact same issue happens. I edited my comment to include my Ruby/Rails version, but I don't think that should be breaking this.

Comment: Could you try... CSV.read('path/file.csv', row_sep: "\n") and see if that changes things?

Comment: is removing the blank line at the end actually solve the problem?

Comment: @UriAgassi Yeah, that does fix it. But I can't really turn in something that's so broken like that.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Yeah, tried that. Still nothing. The row's are seperated by "\r" and the columns are comma delimited. This \n at the end seems to be the only one in the file. Annoying.